# How to use an argument from one function to call another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to pass an argument to one function, which is actually a second function.  Hard to explain so here is some sample code:

```
keyDownEvent("#thisID",nameOfFunctionToRunOnOpen);

function keyDownEvent(id, openFunction) {
$(id).dialog( {
    close: focusOnInput(),
    open: nameOfFunctionToRunOnOpen,
    modal: true,
    show: "clip",
    hide: "fade"
});
}
```

Everything else is standard for my .dialog() calls, just want to modify what happens on Open.  Any idea how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an anonymous function:

```
function keyDownEvent(id, openFunction) {
$(id).dialog( {
    close: focusOnInput(),
    open: function(){openFunction(someArgument);},
    modal: true,
    show: "clip",
    hide: "fade"
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second parameter should be given an actual function object and not just the name of the function in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the function to your second function. Functions are objects in JavaScript and can be saved in variables:

```
function outer(someOtherFunction) {
    someOtherFunction();
}

outer(function () {
    alert('inner function');
});
```